# Google API authorization failing

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

I'm using the Google API (following the Hello Analytics tutorial just to get me started) and having trouble with Authorization. The process is authenticating me, but when I attempt to call the data in from GA I get an error message that I must be logged in for this access. The Authorization button is gone so I can't authenticate, and the "Get Sessions" button appears but results in an error. My example looks exactly like the tutorial example up to the point where the results are processed so I'm really not sure why this is occuring. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code (client id, api key and GA property have been replaced for obvious reasons).

```
var clientId = 'clientid';
var apiKey = 'apikey';
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';


function makeApiCall() {
  var apiQuery = gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
    'ids': 'id',
    'start-date': '2014-06-01',
    'end-date': '2014-07-01',
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews',
    'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
    'filters': 'ga:pagepath=~marketplace/seller/(*.?)/example'
  });
  console.dir(apiQuery);
 apiQuery.execute(handleCoreReportingResults);

}

// This function is called after the Client Library has finished loading
function handleClientLoad() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
  window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}


function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
    loadAnalyticsClient();
  } else {
    handleUnAuthorized();
  }
}


// Authorized user
function handleAuthorized() {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var makeApiCallButton = document.getElementById('make-api-call-button');
  makeApiCallButton.style.visibility = '';
  authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  makeApiCallButton.onclick = makeApiCall;
}


// Unauthorized user
function handleUnAuthorized() {
  var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
  var makeApiCallButton = document.getElementById('make-api-call-button');

  makeApiCallButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
  authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
}


function handleAuthClick(event) {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
  return false;
}


function loadAnalyticsClient() {
  gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3', handleAuthorized);
}

function handleCoreReportingResults(results) {
  if (results.error) {
    console.log('There was an error querying core reporting API: ' + results.message);
  } else {
    console.dir(results);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which tutorial? Please post the link.

Comment: Whoops: https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it works just fine for me.

That leads me to think there's a problem with your project settings in the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com). If there's an origin mismatch or something like that, you won't be able to run queries. Are you running this on a local server? If so, you have to make sure to add `localhost` (with the port you're using) as an approved JavaScript origin when you're creating your client ID.

It would really help if you actually posted the error you were getting, beyond that, I'm not sure I can help you. Like I said, your code works just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not able to run this code at the moment to help you debug it, but my initial suggestion is to *not* do the authentication yourself and instead use the newly released [Google Analytics Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/).

The main selling point of the Embed API is that it handles all this auth stuff for you, so you can very quickly get an app up and running to query the API.

If you want to use it, I'd recommend checking out the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide). After that, take a look at the [demo site](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/demos/embed-api/) to see some examples. You can view source for any of the demos to see how they're made, or the code is on Github.